# Sample rate changes pitch of sine wave, sound() function, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio

I have a small .wav file that I want to play using the sound() function in MATLAB.  I have messed around with it a little bit, and I've found that changing the sampling rate at which I play back the sound also changes the pitch.

Now, my grasp on audio processing, tenuous as it may be, tells me that changing the sampling rate of a sound wave shouldn't change the sound wave's pitch.  But then again, I am playing back the sound in this case, not recording it.  So I'm wondering if the pitch shift I'm seeing is due to a discrepancy between the playback sampling rate and the recording sampling rate.

Is this the case, or am I totally misunderstanding how the sound() function works?

Thanks.

-Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about playing back a 1kHz sine wave at 48kHz sample rate then you have one sine cycle every millisecond or 48 samples. Now if you double the sample rate to 96kHz, the same 48 samples are going to play back in half the time (0.5ms) and the tone coming out the speakers will be at twice the frequency (2kHz).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So this means to get the most accurate playback of a pre-recorded file, i need to play back with the same sampling rate as the sound byte was recorded at?

Comment: Yes, that will give you the best frequency accuracy.